# How to ssh as user X and invoke a command as user Y through a single SSH command line?

Tags: linux, ssh

I can only signon a system as a specific X, using ssh. I want to create an ssh command that allows me to invoke a script on a specific server, but such script needs to be executed as ROOT user.

```
ssh x@myserver.mydomain.com '/app/somescript.sh'
```

The requirement is not to automate this in a single command. If a password is required, that will be fine. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
ssh x@myserver.mydomain.com 'sudo /app/somescript.sh'
```

If you make an appropriate entry in the sudoers file, that is.

Comment: I agree, but is there a somewhat more secure way to avoid the error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` than `NOPASSWD` in the sudoers?

Comment: ssh -t x@myserver.mydomain.com 'sudo /app/somescript.sh'   ... add more t's if it still swears.

Comment: To answer @Kevin, you can set SSH_ASKPASS in the .login of the remote account.  The simple (and, very non-secure) way would be to point it to a shell script that echoes the root password.  A slightly better way would be to have the shell script echo another environment variable.  When you ssh to the remote host, if your sshd_config is setup accordingly, environment variables from your originating account could be passed through to the remote host.  Put the password in an ENV, ssh to the remote host (which has the SSH_ASKPASS set), and sudo won't bother you for a password.

Comment: @Kent: that's actually not quite the right answer; SSH_ASKPASS doesn't prompt for a password, it asks for the passphrase you used when you created your id. And I didn't clutter up my answer because Kevin wasn't the author of the original question.  His problem only occurs if you have done the key-exchange for password-less logins.  Unrelated to the initial question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry gextra, but i don't think this is possible.
you can test it yourself by executing:

```
say This is before; sshx@server.mydomain.com; say This is after
```

the ssh command is in effect until you exit it, then it will execute the next command.
Of course i tried tink's solution, and it gave me an error